# Failed to query Titan's vertex property using Gremlin

Tags: graph, gremlin, titan

I have a sample property graph loaded to Titan with BDB backend. On each vertex, there're 4 properties, namely "**ID**", "first_name", "middle_name" and "last_name". I built unique index on the vertex property "**ID**". The type definition codes are as below.

```
TitanKey keyID = g.makeKey("__ID__").dataType(String.class).indexed(Vertex.class).unique().make();
TitanKey keyFName = g.makeKey("first_name").dataType(String.class).make();
TitanKey keyMName = g.makeKey("middle_name").dataType(String.class).make();
TitanKey keyLName = g.makeKey("last_name").dataType(String.class).make();
//then for each edge label
//using signature to make the DB more compact
TitanLabel lbl = g.makeLabel(label_name).signature(keyID).signature(keyFName).signature(keyMName).signature(keyLName).make();
```

However, when I query the graph via Gremlin (either by the console, i.e., "gremlin.sh" or the REST API), it's strange that seems the vertex properties are "lazy" loaded:

1. If I send the query `"g.v(100).__ID__"`, it will return null;
2. If I send the query `"g.v(100).map.iterate();g.v(100).__ID__"`, it will return the **ID** property.

In the configuration, I disabled storage.transactions, and set storage.read-only as true. Also tried to set the fast-property as true or false, but no difference on the results.

Is there something else have to be configured to avoid the problem?

Comment: I tried to recreate your problem several ways and could not.  Could you please amend your question by including your code for defining the Titan types?  Could you also please clarify your statement on the use of the "console" to create this problem? do you mean the "rexster-console.sh" or the standard "gremlin.sh"?

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I updated the post. For the console, it is standard "gremlin.sh". Actually if I populate the DB without creating the unique index on "__ID__", use the dataType(Object.class) instead of dataType(String.class), and don't use signature() on make edge label, the problem won't occur.

Comment: I'm still unable to recreate the problem, even when using your type definitions.  I have a full Gremlin session that creates a new database, adds the types you defined, adds a vertex, commits() then queries it back as `g.v(4).__ID__` and it seems to return without issue.  I'll ask someone else to take a look and see if they see anything outwardly wrong.  The only other thing I could ask for is the output of a full REPL session that showed the problem.

Comment: Note that my tests were done with Titan 0.4.1.

Comment: Ah, I used Titan 0.4.0. Let me try Titan 0.4.1 first. Thanks!

Comment: When I switch to Titan 0.4.1, seems it's OK now. Thanks!